# check: git rebase done or not?

Tags: git, github

This is the follow up of  ([Alternative to git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603553/alternative-to-git-rebase/39605048?noredirect=1#comment66530401_39605048))

A remoteRepo has two branches, Master and testBranch. testBranch is 100 commits ahead and some 4000 commits behind. Changes were made to testBranch but were never incorporated to Master.

So I wanted to rebase testBranch onto master and give them a pull request. so that they can review and merge it.

I did the following to achieve the above:

1. Forked and cloned the remoteRepo locally
2. git checkout testBranch
3. git fetch origin
4. git rebase origin/Master
5. Resolved conflicts

But when i was resolving conflicts, 
    `git rebase --continue`
It said, `No rebase in progress?`. So checked `git status`,

```
On branch testBranch
Your branch and 'origin/testBranch' have diverged,
and have 4737 and 65 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

Then i made `git commit`. After that, again checked the status

```
On branch testBranch
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/testBranch' by 4739 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Finally did `git push` and checked status

```
To https://github.com/vishnu/proj.git
8d132f4..c192ff7  testBranch -> testBranch
```

I went manually to the forked repo and checked. It shows that Master is some 30 commits behind proj:master. testBranch is  4739 comits ahead of proj:testBranch.

I don't know what has happend. since my idea is to rebase testBranch onto master, i thought that master of my fork finally would have more commits ahead and i can give them a pull request of it.

or whatever done is correct and Should i give pull request of this testBranch ?

what has happend here?

Any guidelines would be very helpful for me.

Comment: after resolving conflicts, `git rebase --continue` should reflect your commits on the master branch. Are u sure that the rebase completed? Did git "replay" your `testBranch`'s commits on top of `master`?

Comment: Not clear, but looks to me like during the rebase there were some additional commits to master, upstream. Pull and rebase again.

Comment: That looks like you did a merge, not a rebase.  `All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)`

Comment: Another possibility is that you incorrectly rebased the `master` branch onto the `testBranch` branch instead of rebasing the`testBranch` branch onto the `master` branch. (Ie. you did `git rebase testbranch` on the master branch instead of `git rebase master` on the testBranch branch)

Comment: Try to visualize the commit graph (either with `gitk --all` or `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`) and check what happened to your commits

Answer (score 0):

You rebased the testBranch onto master you created a new history, your 100 commits were put atop the 4000+ changes from master. In the end you have the observed 4739 commits difference to proj:testBranch. proj:master is only 30 commits behind because apparently when fixing the merge conflicts you inadvertently squashed multiple commits in one fix.

Rebase always works just on the branch you're at that moment, i.e. only local testbranch changed before push -f (proj:testBranch).